# How to specify rewrite rule for Webrick?

Tags: url-rewriting, ruby-on-rails

I am running on Webrick with rails/angular html5mode enabled application. I would like to achieve this:

Server side

```
Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)
```

Is it possibly with webrick? I would like to stick with webrick for my development enviroment.

Comment: Suggest that you might try StackOverflow SE for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I wouldn't.

I like development environments to exactly match live environments.  So if you're using Thin in production, use Thin for development, for example.